# Closed curves with minimal total curvature in the unit circle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, inequalities, curvature, curves

Chakerian proved in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103036705) that a closed curve of length  L in the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has [total curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_curvature) at least L.

In [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2034901?seq=1) later paper Chakerian gave a simpler proof and noted that equality holds iff the curve is of length $2\pi n$ and winds round the unit circle $n$ times.

Assume that the closed curve is smooth (no corners) and we are working in $\mathbb{R}^2$. My question is:

**For closed curves with length $4\pi> L>2\pi$ within the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (and hence non-convex) what is the minimal total curvature and for which curves is this attained?**